# How to unpack a war file copied from local directory using Maven Resources Plugin?

Tags: maven, tomcat, cas

I am trying integrating CAS server with a Spring application. (I have configured CAS locally, in my Tomcat server and it is working properly). Using Maven Resources Plugin I copied the `cas.war` file to my Web app's target folder. But I need to unpack that `cas.war` file in order to overwrite some files that I have modified.

How can I unpack this `war` file which I have copied using Maven Resources Plugin`?

Here is my pom.xml

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <warName>cas</warName>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/web.xml</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-jetty-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <webApp>
                    <contextPath>/cas</contextPath>
                </webApp>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!--Copy plugin-->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <executions>

                <!--copy cas.war file-->
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-initial-cas.war</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/cas</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${CAS.LOCATION}/target</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>cas.war</include>
                                </includes>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>


                <!--copying deployerConfigContext file-->
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-deployerConfigContext</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/cas/WEB-INF</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${basedir}/resources</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>deployerConfigContext.xml</include>
                                </includes>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>


                <!--copying web.xml file-->
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-web.xml</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/cas/WEB-INF</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${basedir}/resources</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>web.xml</include>
                                </includes>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>


                <!--copying casdatabase.properties file-->
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-casdatabase.properties</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/cas/WEB-INF</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${basedir}/resources</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>casdatabase.properties</include>
                                </includes>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <!--unpacking plugin-->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unzip-war</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <echo message="unpack cas.war" />
                            <unzip src="${basedir}/target/cas/cas.war" dest="${basedir}/target/cas" overwrite="true"/>
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Comment: It might not be necessary to unpack the file. Look at http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.2/tomcat7-maven- plugin/redeploy-mojo.html

Comment: @Kennet Thank you, but it is not something about redeploying. I need to CAS-ify an application by getting a copy of the locally installed cas.war file and modifying some files according to the app and rebuilding it. If you can have a look into my pom.xml please.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to override resources inside a war, you should be using the maven overlay method.

Comment: Yes, I wish to copy the original cas.war file which I have configured in my tomcat to the target folder of my webapp developing in IntelliJ IDEA. Also then need to unpack it and copy and replace some resources files inside that unpacked war. Can it be done by using overlay plugin?